# Undefined behaviour of the compiler

Tags: c

Hey what will be the the output of the following code, it is not working as it should.

```
int j=65;
printf("j>=65?%d:%c",j);
```

In this case it should print: `j>=65`, and then match the next `%d` with the `j` so print `65`, and then `%c` is printing `l` how the `l` is printed.

Comment: Sorry, to me, it is completely unclear what your question is. Please check your spelling, grammar and punctuation.

Comment: Hey i have edited my post hope now u may understand it better .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format specifier `"j>=65?%d:%c"` has two `%...` pieces, they indicate that two values are to be printed. The format is used within `printf("j>=65?%d:%c",j);` which only provides one value to be printed.

There is no checking in C that the `printf` is given the correct number of arguments for the format, there is no protection at run time for what actually happens when too few arguments are given. That is undefined behaviour. The C language allows the programmer to write many things that lead to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
Printf("j>=65?%d:%c",j);
```

there has to be at least

```
printf("j>=65?%d:%c",j);
```

The code has undefined behaviour because the number of format specifiers is greater than the number of following arguments.

I think you mean the following

```
printf( j >= 65 ? "%d" : "%c", j );
```

in this case there will be outputed 65.

Comment: Its giving it right but an extra "l" character is printed. I can't understand why . its "L" not i. And its not wht i mean i just wrote it right.

Comment: @user3863058 I do not see where an extra character is outputed in the shown by me statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use conditional operation inside double quotes like this `printf("j>=65?%d:%c",j);`. you are having two format specifier and only one argument. so it results in undefined behavior. so `j>=65?` is printed first, `%d` prints `65`, `%c` expects arguments, but there is no arguments, so it prints anything. Results in undefined behavior. You should use No of arguments equal to the no of format specifiers.

When i run your code in my system i got-

```
root@ubuntu:~/c/basics# cc con1.c
con1.c: In function ‘main’:
con1.c:6:1: warning: format ‘%c’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat=] // see this warning
printf("j>=65?%d:%c",j);
^
root@ubuntu:~/c/basics# ./a.out 
j>=65?65:� // see this undefined symbol
```

Try the following change and fix it-

```
printf(j>=65 ? "%d" : "%c",j);
```

when the condition is true it prints `65` and when condition fails it prints the character(For that input value)

or

```
j>=65 ? printf("%d",j) : printf("%c",j);
```

Comment: I m not using conditional operator i m just trying to do this nd this is not working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You call printf() with two format specifiers, but pass only one parameter after the format string. The function doesn't know how many parameters you pass, so it assumes you did pass two arguments. The result is, it reads the random garbage that just happens to be at the memory location where would be the second parameter if you did pass it. Run it another day, compile it with different compiler or different options, and you get different result (in worst case, segmentation fault).